# Change sheet's Zoom for inactive page

Tags: excel, vba

As you know you may change sheet's zoom with the following code:

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
```

Is there a way to change zoom of inactive sheet?

Thanks

Comment: @SergeyRyabov Would be great if you either accept my answer or give a feedback to it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not that beautiful, but it works.

```
Sub SetZoom()

mySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'both Sheet IDs and names will work here
zoomIt = Application.InputBox("What's the zoom-in-sheet?")

'go to that sheet (where you want to zoom in)
Sheets(zoomIt).Select

'put in zoom factor (e.g. 300)
zoomFactor = Application.InputBox("How much is the fi-- er.. zoom?")

'boom! zoomed!
ActiveWindow.Zoom = zoomFactor

'select your old sheet
Sheets(mySheet).Select


End Sub
```

Sayonara.

Comment: `y` is unassigned. It's just a draft, better to rework your code to make it complete procedure, taking parameters, e. g. the name of worksheet where zoom should be changed and target zoom value.